# How to connect lines after probabilistic Hough transform?

Tags: opencv, lines, hough-transform, dotted-line, straight-line-detection

I am trying to find a cross on image. Here are the steps:
1. Canny operator
2. Probabilistic Hough transformation

=> set of sections - on the image.

I want to connect the dotted lines in order to get few long segments. 
Unfortunately, I didn't find any standard tool to do that:

1. Standard Hough transformation - returns infinite lines, so it is not useful.
2. Dilation - cannot connect dotted lines.

Any ideas are welcome..

[image]

UPDATE:

Don't have the exact source of above image right now, but here is the one of the examples.

[image]

Comment: can you upload your source image?

Comment: I had to do the same thing. I did the straigthforward way. For each line, compute the slope and the intercept. Compare the different slope and intercept to see which match together.

Comment: Yes, that is an option. But I was looking for something more elegant. May be another tricky transformation or second Hough transformation on these lines.